# Node.JS WriteFile - File of specific size

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to specify the size/length of a file and have the system reserve the space needed?
I'm looking for something like:

```
fs.write('file', Buffer, 1024*1024*54); // To create 54MB file.
```

Comment: See [this example](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain) for a decent implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_size) of that size?

```
fs.writeFile('file', new Buffer(1024*1024*54));
```

Comment: It's late. I was using a String as the size.

Comment: This doesn't work above `1024*1024*1024 - 1`. If you need bigger, you'll need something like `fs.writeFile('file', new Buffer(1024*1024*1024 - 1), function () { fs.appendFile('file', new Buffer(1), function () { console.log('all done') }) })`

Comment: @Shawn could you reference source, or explain your comment, please?